# How can I remove file from downloading list and send it into the downloaded file list?

Tags: android, listview, service, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I'm building a download manager app which can download multiples in parallel. I'm showing the downloading files in a `listview` where each item has a `progressbar` showing the download progress.

When a file is dowloaded I want to remove that item from the list. I'm sending progress from service class using `localbroadcast` `manager` and updating the list using `broadcast receiver`.

When a item is removed **the app crushes** showing `IndexOutOfBounds` `Exception` saying index is 1 size is 1.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your list indexing starts with 0. If you have one element in a list you should access it at index 0 like this

```
list.get(0); //the first element is received
```